# Any way to wipe a hard drive that won't mount?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

I have an iMac and a 12-inch MacBook. I also have an external hard drive.

The hard drive won't mount on either machine. I can't see it in finder or in disk utility. The weird thing is that I can feel the drive spinning. I don't believe that it's ever been dropped or damaged, and it's designed specifically to withstand abuse.

When I asked Google this question, every answer was about sending it to a data recovery place, but I've duplicated this drive in a partition on my 3TB drive, so the data isn't important. Is there any way to simply wipe this drive clean and start over?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [SMART Error for HDD, cannot mount drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1276914/smart-error-for-hdd-cannot-mount-drive/1276919#1276919).

If any of that works, then you can reuse the drive, otherwise, that drive is not usable.  If you feel the need to securely make sure the data is not recoverable, take apart the drive and bend the platters.

Even if the drive is able to be recovered, it's no longer a reliable drive, so don't keep anything on it that you need, and expect more trouble with it in the near future.

Edit: BTW, the drive spinning simply means it has power.